# Compose Material 3 Theme customization

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

Can we customize colors and provide only our custom colors for theeme in jetpack compose material 3?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You can get detailed documentation on how to create custom color schemes in official documentation:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I meaned that custom color scheme out of material 3 for example ;
primary = md_theme_dark_primary,
not named primary . like below
myCustomColor = md_theme_dark_primary,